# how many SPI slaves dsPIC33EP series MCU can drive at the same time?

Tags: pic, spi

I am designing a data acquisition system:a dsPIC33EPxxx MCU collect data and coordinate several (would like to have 28 of them) ADS1248 ADCs by SPI bus. A start conversion command will be sent simultaneously to all slaves and conversion result will be collected one by one. all chips will be on the same PCB with small distance to MCU. Does the SPI module of PIC power enough to drive all slaves at the same time?

Comment: related question about SPI: [Arduino SPI limit](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/36473/7036)

Comment: I think this is more of a question related to the physical/PCB layout and routing problem, I do not doubt 28 slaves exceed any upper limit of SPI spec and my MCU do have 28 spare pins for chip select. SCLK, MOSI and MISO are shared.

Comment: Check the datasheet, look for the gpio current, then find the ADS1248 current for the input pins. Then use logic. Or google fanout

Answer (score 1):

SPI slaves can be selected by dedicated Slave select pin  `SS`  or chip select pin `CS`.  But, no MCU will have more than 10 chip selects I think. Hence, I propose below way of handling the 28 slaves. I have done the same for SPI flash devices and was able to upgrade firmware of all 32 SPI flash, one at a time, using one controller.

If the command for all slaves is common, then the `MOSI` pins of all slaves can be **shorted together** and also the clock pins. The `MISO` pins and `SS` pins of all the slaves are connected to the master's `MISO` and `SS` via multiplexer. The master issues the measure command, and then sequentially selects the slave `MISO` and `CS` pins to read the data via multiplexer. Since, only one slave is connected to the master, rest all slaves will ignore the data read command.

While issueing the measure command, the `CS` of all the slave devices should be low, which has to be taken care of with an add on circuit. This is required only if there is a need to issue measure command to all the slaves at the same instant.

Shorting of multiple pins will demand slowing down the clock frequency of `SPICLK` due to added capacitance of many slaves. In worst case, it may be needed to buffer in two stages.

Edit: Since. `CS` pins aer GPIOs of MCU, they can be connected directly to all the slaves without any buffer. the `SPICLK`, `SPIMISO` an `SPIMOSI` needs to be buffered.

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC4050.pdf is better suitable compared to my earlier suggestion. still, it works.

A simple opamp used as voltage follower can be used to buffer at least 8 slave inputs.

[TLV2462](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv2464.pdf) is one such example which can be used as voltage follower (buffer) for `MOSI` and `CLK`. It is a rail to rail opamp and can be used to buffer the present load. Add a small resistor at the output pin of opamp if the output seems to have ringing effect.

Comment: "While issueing the measure command, the CS of all the slave devices should be low, which has to be taken care of with an add on circuit. This is required only if there is a need to issue measure command to all the slaves at the same instant." this is actually what i need. so you suggesting an opamp buffer on sclk? Thanks to bring this out but chip select will be handled by normal IO pins, i don't use CS pins from SPI module, so that's not an issue for me.

Comment: if you are bit banging, then you just have to wait for more time after you drive CS low, so that, CS has settled to logic zero safely. three buffers can be used for both CS and SPICLK(which is also driven by GPIO i assume)

Comment: are you really using 26 spare GPIO pins of MCU for multiple CS? it can also be handled via mux.. but, if free pins are there, MCU lines are better to use a CS, as it reduces the burden of handling Chip select during measure command and read command.

Comment: I fully disagree with the idea of using an opamp to buffer a logic signal. Opamps have slow slew rate and are made for analog operations. On the other hand, there are buffer gates made specially for this purpose, like 74HC4050. They are much faster (6ns delay), consume much less power (1/20th the power of TLV2462), are way, way cheaper, and, as an additional benefit, combine multiple gates in a single package.

Comment: @dim thanks.  I oriented towards finding suitable opamp because, I felt from OP's first comment above that was expected when opamp buffer was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> how many SPI slaves dsPIC33EP series MCU can drive at the same time?

1 per SPI module.

> Does the SPI module of PIC power enough to drive all slaves at the same time?

Yes, within reason -> ie, the SPI slaves aren't terribly designed.